# Conversion of 01 to jan , 02 to feb including year in the field

Tags: oracle

I have a field containing 201402, 201404, here I want to convert 02 to Feb and 04 to April. Is it possible to do that? This field contains entries of all months. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot that you can do in terms of [datetime format models](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) within Oracle. A simple example below (replace the string literal within the TO_DATE(...) with your field if it is a string or replace the entire TO_DATE with your field if it is already of data type DATE):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('201402','YYYYMM'),'YYYY-MONTH') FROM DUAL;
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('201404','YYYYMM'),'YYYY-MONTH') FROM DUAL;
```